# CMAKE Find file based on extension

Tags: cmake

How can I find a file inside a directory based on the file extension?

I want to create a function that finds a linker script. The function will be defined in the toolchain file, because each compiler has a different type of linker script.

I want to pass to the function a path to a directory with linker files for all type of supported compilers.
The function implemented for the specific compiler will find the right linker file (for example, armcc compiler will find the file with the extension .sct)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's [`file(GLOB)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) but in the documentation it's recommended not to do something like this.

Comment: I ended up using file(GLOB CONFIGURE_DEPENDS) which solves the issues raised by does who don't recommend it.